# Download files to user device using php

Tags: php, download

I have a website where user can click on the download button and the file in my drive will get downloaded in the user device. I made a code and it works file when I am doing it on laptop, then for testing I used KSWEB (for localhost server on my android). when I download the file in android it gets downloaded but in htdocs folder which is a folder of the web server KSWEB just same as the htdocs of XAMPP in computer. Now I am worried what will happen when user will download the file, where will it get stored? or will it give any other error like path does not exist? How can I download the file in all of the devices.
this the code which I have tried and which works in laptop

```
$dir = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH").'\Downloads\\';
$filelink="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Tvoj7JFUaL3RKWOHiLjsJZHUIEgVqriu&export=media";
$file=file_get_contents($filelink);
$s=file_put_contents($dir."file3.doc",$file);
```

Comment: PHP is server side, it have no access to client side storage (unless in development environemnt where the server and client are on same machine)

Comment: This code doesn't "download" anything, it just saves data to the local filesystem where the code is running. When you're testing on your laptop, that happens to be the same machine where the browser is, but that's not what it's like for a live application.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/amp/ for how to do it properly - and safely

Comment: P s. In this particular case though, why not just  put a hyperlink to Google drive directly in the web page instead of proxying via PHP?

Comment: `Now I am worried what will happen when user will download the file, where will it get stored?`.. if you implement it properly (as per my previous comments) it will be stored wherever the browser is configured to store downloads. I assume you must have downloaded files from websites before? If so then you should know already how the experience works for the end user.

Comment: @ADyson thank you, i will work at your solution

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, it was not the exact solution but did gave me the idea which eventually lead to what I wanted. thanks a lot

Comment: That's great, glad you were able to solve it. please post your solution as an Answer below so it may be of benefit to others with a similar situation. If it is well received, others may upvote it and increase your reputation :-). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to download the file using the drive link

```
//Remote download URL
$remoteURL = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1p03NXA7Mt0hCmW0ql3xbGOm2-Df3Lf2Q&export=media';
$name="SE-19012 Maha Javed Assignment 1.docx";
$extension = pathinfo($title, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($extension="pdf")
{
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");

}
else
{
    header("Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
}
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($name));
ob_end_clean();
readfile($remoteURL);
exit;
```